# Convergence with differential

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

suppose $f$ is differentialbe on $[0,\infty)$, and $f'(x)\geq 0$, $f(0)>0$. Furthermore, $$\int_0^ \infty  \frac{dx}{f(x)+f'(x)}<\infty,$$
show that $$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{f(x)}<\infty.$$

this troubles me for several days. My idea is $e^x(f(x)+f'(x))=(e^xf(x))'$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{f(x)}{\rm d}x-\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{f(x)+f'(x)}{\rm d}x&\leq\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{f^2(x)}{\rm d}x\\
&\left.-\frac{1}{f(x)}\right|_{0}^{+\infty}\leq\frac{1}{f(0)}
\end{align*}
Thus, $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{f(x)}{\rm d}x$ converges.